# Triangle border on circle

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make triangle border inside of circle using css, I'm close, but still not there. Any ideas?  
[image]

Here is My Code

```css
div { background: #1063a7; width: 80px; height: 80px; position: relative; text-align: center; } div:before, div:after { content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 80px; width: 80px; background: #1063a7; } div:before { -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); -moz-transform: rotate(30deg); -ms-transform: rotate(30deg); -o-transform: rotate(30deg); } div:after { -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg); -moz-transform: rotate(60deg); -ms-transform: rotate(60deg); -o-transform: rotate(60deg); }
```

```html
<body>
    <div></div> 
</body>
```

Comment: Any Solution without Canvas or svg ?

Comment: There is a CSS answer also in that thread.

Comment: Yes,You're right , but, it is possible with use only one div ?

Comment: The answer says *This is possible with CSS but after 12 points, requires more than one div.* So I'd guess that no, it's not

Comment: Ok, Thanx for your input